# UIPath Orchestrator based Automation: Schedule Job Fails due to robot unavailability

Tags: uipath-orchestrator

I have my `GCP machine` that is scheduled to switch on and run from 6hrs in the morning to 12hrs. I am trying to automate the script once the machine is on, so I am scheduling a job on 6:30 hrs.

But what I observed is that `UIPath Robot` doesn't automatically get connected unless I open an `RDP session` and then manually open `UI Path Assistant` to connect it with `orchestrator`.

I also tried to create a `bat script` and schedule it with windows startup. But that fails to run as well. To verify my `startup script` I added two commands:

- `<verification script sending mail on startup>` && `<UIPath Script>`

I tested this script manually in `RDP session` and they did run sequentially as expected. But when I added it to `auto-scheduling` in gcp, only the first script actually ran (`<verification script sending mail on startup>`) and the second one (`<UIPath Script>`) just didn't.

Moreover I did put the `bat` file in `Windows Startup` Folder but again that also required me to sign into the system using `RDP` session for it to run.

From my understanding, the `UIPath Script (XAML)` in order to run needs the system to be switched on 24/7 and then it connects to `orchestrator` and then we can schedule the process based on the time, but then my maching will be `idle` for lots of ineffective hours.

Secondly, going by the `.bat` file to be as a startup script also fails as in order to run the script, it needs the user to be logged in which doesn't happen. Though other scripts such as `.py` files run smoothly so I lose here as well.

Finally scheduling my `bat` file through `windows startup` feature does work but then it's also of no use as for it to start also I need to open an `RDP session` and log in.

Does anyone know the workaround for this?